# Linux using grep to print the file name and first n characters

Tags: linux, grep

How do I use grep to perform a search which, when a match is found, will print the file name as well as the first n characters in that file?  Note that `n` is a parameter that can be specified and it is irrelevant whether the first n characters actually contains the matching string.

Answer (score 5):

```
grep -l pattern *.txt | 
    while read line; do 
        echo -n "$line: "; 
        head -c $n "$line"; 
        echo; 
     done
```

Change `-c` to `-n` if you want to see the first `n` lines instead of bytes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pipe the output of grep to sed to accomplish what you want.  Here is an example:

```
grep mypattern *.txt | sed 's/^\([^:]*:.......\).*/\1/'
```

The number of dots is the number of characters you want to print.  Many versions of sed often provide an option, like -r (GNU/Linux) and -E (FreeBSD), that allows you to use modern-style regular expressions.  This makes it possible to specify numerically the number of characters you want to print.

```
N=7
grep mypattern *.txt /dev/null | sed -r "s/^([^:]*:.{$N}).*/\1/"
```

Note that this solution is a lot more efficient that others propsoed, which invoke multiple processes.

Comment: On my linux machine sed does not accept a -E (grep does though). It does however work with -r

Comment: He is looking for the first N characters of the file, not N matching characters.  Also, add /dev/null in there in case *.txt evaluates to 0 or 1 files.  E.g. grep mypattern *.txt /dev/null | sed ...

Comment: The extended RE pattern I gave will not match lines with fewer than N characters, and these will therefore be correctly printed according to the specification.  You are right about the need for adding the /dev/null argument.

Answer (score 3):

There are few tools that print 'n characters' rather than 'n lines'.  Are you sure you really want characters and not lines?  The whole thing can perhaps be best done in Perl.  As specified (using `grep`), we can do:

```
pattern="$1"
shift
n="$2"
shift
grep -l "$pattern" "$@" |
while read file
do
    echo "$file:" $(dd if="$file" count=${n}c)
done
```

The quotes around `$file` preserve multiple spaces in file names correctly. We can debate the command line usage, currently (assuming the command name is '`ngrep`'):

```
 ngrep pattern n [file ...]
```

---

I note that @litb used '`head -c $n`'; that's neater than the `dd` command I used. There might be some systems without `head` (but they'd pretty archaic).  I note that the POSIX version of `head` only supports `-n` and the number of lines; the `-c` option is probably a GNU extension.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts here:

1) If efficiency was not a concern (like that would ever happen), you could check *$status* [csh] after running *grep* on each file.  E.g.:  (For **N** characters **= 25**.)

```
foreach FILE ( file1 file2 ... fileN )
  grep targetToMatch  ${FILE} > /dev/null
  if ( $status == 0 ) then
     echo -n "${FILE}:  "
     head -c25 ${FILE}
  endif
end
```

2) GNU [FSF] *head* contains a *--verbose* *[-v]* switch.  It also offers *--null*, to accomodate filenames with spaces.  And there's *'--'*, to handle filenames like *"-c"*.  So you could do:

```
grep --null -l targetToMatch -- file1 file2 ... fileN |
xargs --null head -v -c25 --
```